# How to FORCE IMPLICIT cast from "explicit" text to uuid

Tags: postgresql

Postgres version 10.0

I have a table my_table with column my_guid of type uuid.

I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE my_guid='{239919b2-88ca-4138-b17c-a066a7d5724a}';
```

Notice these parentheses, there are no parentheses in the database.
However, when the GUID is present, I get results.
Therefore, some implicit text-to-uuid casting takes place.

The problem is that the ORM that I use builds queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE my_guid='{239919b2-88ca-4138-b17c-a066a7d5724a}'::text;
```

And this query fails with an error stating that there is no uuid = text operator. 
(Kinda silly, I think).

I need to "teach" my database to perform implicit text-to-uuid casting when the text is explicitly cast to text :-)

Can you help me?

Comment: `'{239919b2-88ca-4138-b17c-a066a7d5724a}'` is a valid UUID literal  it's not "text" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html You need to tell your obfuscation layer to get rid of the stupid cast or better: to use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: It will be better when you teach your ORM not to do stupid things.